# In mobile view - picture with padding in container and in desktop view its not happenning

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, padding

Trying to set this for all email providers, usually crashes for outlook when it works for ltus notes and vice versa. The ideal result is on the pictures underneath. Padding around the pictures on mobile version and none on desktop one.
[MOBILE VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6r2v5.jpg)

[DESKTOP VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qbe4.jpg)

```html
<!-- //////////// Two column no padding Right Image block x2  Start //////////// -->
<table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w600" style=" background: #282830;" width="600">

    <tr>
        <td align="left" class="mobileshow" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"
            valign="top" width="17">
            <img alt="" border="0" class="mobileshow" height="10"
                src="https://image.crm.toyota-europe.com/lib/fe9a13727767047b74/m/3/6d01e7ca-c353-4732-942d-dd87573c9245.gif"
                style="display:block" width="17"></td>
        <td align="left" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;"
            valign="top">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="hide"
                style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;"
                width="300">

                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="hide" valign="top">
                        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="We didn’t stop at features" border="0" class="hide "
                                height="300"
                                src="https://image.crm.toyota-europe.com/lib/fe9a13727767047b74/m/3/f7e1c645-d8f1-47e7-a3d3-62d92ad5b6ba.jpg"
                                style="display:block" width="300"></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="left" bgcolor="#323238" class="w284" valign="top" width="300">
            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="mobilecontent w284">

                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="w284 mobilecontent" valign="top">
                        <!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
                        <div class="mobilecontent" style="display:none; max-height:0; overflow:hidden;">
                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w284" width="284">

                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" class="mobilecontent " valign="top">
                                        <img alt="We didn’t stop at features" border="0" height="259"
                                            src="https://image.crm.toyota-europe.com/lib/fe9a13727767047b74/m/3/a2e94a65-70ec-406a-ab58-67be08ffb745.jpg"
                                            style="display:block" width="284"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!--<![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table align="left" bgcolor="#323238" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w284"
                style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" width="298">

                <tr>
                    <td align="left" class="w18" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"
                        valign="top" width="40">
                        <img alt="" border="0" class="w18" height="10"
                            src="https://image.crm.toyota-europe.com/lib/fe9a13727767047b74/m/3/6d01e7ca-c353-4732-942d-dd87573c9245.gif"
                            style="display:block" width="40"></td>
                    <td align="left" class="w240"
                        style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;" valign="top"
                        width="240">
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w240" width="240">

                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="h12" valign="top">
                                    <img alt="" border="0" class="h12" height="54"
                                        src="https://image.crm.toyota-europe.com/lib/fe9a13727767047b74/m/3/6d01e7ca-c353-4732-942d-dd87573c9245.gif"
                                        style="display:block" width="10"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="font_2_col_head"
                                    style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;font-family:ToyotaType, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:15px;color:#FFFFFF;font-weight:bold;line-height:21px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;"
                                    valign="middle">
                                    <strong class="font_2_col_head" style="font-size: 15px;">We didn&rsquo;t stop at
                                        features</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="h8" height="14"
                                    style="font-size:0;letter-spacing:0;line-height:14px;padding:0;margin:0;"
                                    valign="top">
                                    <img alt="" border="0" class="h8" height="14"
                                        src="https://image.crm.toyota-europe.com/lib/fe9a13727767047b74/m/3/6d01e7ca-c353-4732-942d-dd87573c9245.gif"
                                        style="display:block" width="10"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" class="w240" valign="middle">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="w240" width="240">

                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" class="font_2_col_copy"
                                                style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;font-family:ToyotaTypeNormal, Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:15px;color:#cecfd0;font-weight:normal;line-height:23px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;"
                                                valign="middle">
                                                Thanks to Apple CarPlay&trade; and Android Auto&trade; smartphone
                                                integration, a 10&rdquo; Head-up Display (HUD) and 8-speaker JBL audio
                                                system, the premium feature list is never-ending in the all-new
                                                Yaris&nbsp;Hybrid.</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="left" class="h16" valign="top">
                                                <img alt="" border="0" class="h16" height="13"
                                                    src="https://image.crm.toyota-europe.com/lib/fe9a13727767047b74/m/3/6d01e7ca-c353-4732-942d-dd87573c9245.gif"
                                                    style="display:block" width="10"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" class="w32" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"
                        valign="top" width="10">
                        <img alt="" border="0" class="w32" height="10"
                            src="https://image.crm.toyota-europe.com/lib/fe9a13727767047b74/m/3/6d01e7ca-c353-4732-942d-dd87573c9245.gif"
                            style="display:block" width="10"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td align="left" class="mobileshow" style="border-collapse:collapse;mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"
            valign="top" width="17">
            <img alt="" border="0" class="mobileshow" height="10"
                src="https://image.crm.toyota-europe.com/lib/fe9a13727767047b74/m/3/6d01e7ca-c353-4732-942d-dd87573c9245.gif"
                style="display:block" width="17"></td>
    </tr>
</table><!-- //////////// Two column no padding Right Image block x2  //////////// END-->
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this question is asking - is it like this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62874265/setting-a-content-stacking-order-in-mobile-html-emails -- otherwise please explain the question more: e.g. what is actually going wrong for you? ("crashing" makes no sense)

Comment: Is the questoin, perhaps, how to get padding on mobile around an image, but not on desktop?

Answer (score 0):

try to use @media

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

works in Gmail Mobile App, check others email providers by yourself (I don't know what providers do you use)